# How to overwrite flash memory on STM32L series of microcontrollers

Tags: microcontroller, flash-memory, stm32l152

I am trying to write a known pattern (ie 0xFFFFFFFF or 0x00000000) on top of already written flash memory, to invalidate portions of it for a primitive file system. But it doesn't work for me on the STM32L series as it does on the STM32F series.

I am used to the STM32F family of microcontrollers, where the flash memory is erased to 0xFFFFFFFF and written with 0's.  You can write anything you want to erase memory, ie

```
 write 0x00001234 on top of 0xFFFFFFFF -> 0x00001234
```

and you can write 0x00000000 (all zeros) on top of anything

```
 write 0x00000000 on top of 0x00001234 -> 0x0000000
```

I am now using the STM32L family (low power), and the flash memory is totally different. It is erased to 0x00000000, and written with 1's. However, I don't know how to reliably write all ones.  For example, if I erase, I can do this

```
 write 0x01020304 on top of 0x00000000 -> 0x01020304
```

but if I try

```
 write 0xFFFFFFFF on top of 0x01020304 -> 0xFFFFFFBF !!!
```

Note that the final answer has a *B* in it. It is not all ones. In fact, if I write bytes 0x00 to 0xFF to a freshly erased page of memory, and then write 0xFFFFFFFFFF all over it, I get very glitchy results:

```
ff ff ff bf ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff fb
f7 ff ff ff fd ff ff ff ff ff ff f7 ff ff ff ff
fe ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff 7f f7 ff ff ff
ff ff ff fb ff ff ff ef ff ff ff ff ff ff ff df
fe ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff 7f f7 ff ff ff
ff ff ff fb ff ff ff ef ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
ff ff ff bf ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff fb
f7 ff ff ff fd ff ff ff ff ff ff f7 ff ff ff df
f7 ff ff ff fd ff ff ff ff ff ff f7 fe ff ff ff
ff ff ff bf ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff fd ff ff ff
ff ff ff fb ff ff ff ef ff ff ff ff ff ff ff bf
fe ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff 7f fb ff ff ff
ff ff ff fb ff ff ff ef ff ff ff ff ff ff ff bf
fe ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff 7f ff ff ff ef
f7 ff ff ff fd ff ff ff ff ff ff f7 fe ff ff ff
ff ff ff bf ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff fb ff ff ff
```

Here is the pseudo code I am using (FlashWrite is a wrapper around the STM std periph library).  I tried writing a  pattern of 8 writes with the bits shifted <<1 each time, and that actually gave me what I wanted (all ones) but I am not sure this is reliable.

```
 uint32_t pattern = 0x04030201;
 FlashErasePage(0x0801E000,FLASH_PASSWORD);
 for(int j=0;j<64;j++) {
    FlashWriteArray(0x0801E000 + 4*j,(uint8_t*)&pattern,4);
    pattern += 0x04040404;
 }

 for(int j=0;j<64;j++) {
#if 1
     // write once
     uint32_t pattern = 0xFFFFFFFF;
     FlashWriteArray(0x0801E000 + 4*j,(uint8_t*)&pattern,4);
#else
     // write shifting bit pattern
     uint32_t pattern = 0x01010101;
     for(int i=0;i<8;i++) {
        FlashWriteArray(0x0801E000 + 4*j,(uint8_t*)&pattern,4);
        pattern <<=1;
     }
#endif
```

Comment: You might consider asking for this question to be migrated to the [Electrical Engineering stack-exchange site](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/) as that site seems to deal with microcontrollers more.

Comment: @dwelch I think this is a result of ECC, which results in another layer of processing logic being applied to the data, and then the choice of defining 1 or 0 becomes more arbitrary.

Comment: @dwelch - STM32L is low *power*, not low end. And I don't know if the F series has ECC or not, it might be differently implemented.

Comment: The STM32L are relatively new and can shut down to 0.5 microamps, which is not bad for a 32 bit ARM core. They do have a lot of features too (USB, touch, LCD, AES, FSMC, SDIO ++). The only thing they don't have is high speed or gobs of memory.